# How do i remove a superfluous parent directory

Tags: git

I have a directory structure like this

-foo
   -bar

i actually want the repo to be the following:

-bar

how do i remove foo without having to delete and recreate the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git mv` -> Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink

`git mv source_dir/ destination_dir/`